# Where are the config files for pip installed packages in Ubuntu 14?

Tags: python, pypi, radicale

I am trying to install [radicale](http://radicale.org/) on **Ubuntu 14** and I need to change the config file, which is supposed to be located either 
`/etc/radicale/config` or `~/.config/radicale/config`.

However, installing with pip `sudo pip install radicale` neither of the radicale directories are created.

Where are the config files for pip installed packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, none of those configuration files exist, just go ahead and create one system wide `/etc/radicale/config` or for particular user `~/.config/radicale/config` or even both, `radicale` will read them in this order, first system wide and then the users one and after that it will check for `RADICALE_CONFIG` environment variable and try to read configuration file it's pointing to as well.

Default configuration values can be found in `config.py` inside `radicale` module.

```
$ python -c "import radicale; print(radicale)"
<module 'radicale' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/radicale/__init__.pyc'>
```

So `config.py` will be located at:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/radicale/config.py
```